# Zero and initialize a C structure

Tags: c, struct

I have a struct that I want to zero and then set the members. I tried this:

```
cmdRequest_t cmdRequest = {0};
cmdRequest = {3, "d t"};
```

but that doesn't work. I have also tried several variants, but I always get a syntax error on that second line. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you provide the definition for cmdRequest_t?

Comment: how do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: That assignment syntax is not usable in C.  You are trying to use an initialization list with an assignment statement and you can't do that. You will need to assign the individual members one at a time.

Comment: Btw `_t` is a reserved suffix

Comment: What's the point of doing "zero", if you want to "assign" afterwards anyway?

Comment: @LogicG8 it's better off without the definition, then we have no chance of giving a non-general answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply do:

```
cmdRequest_t cmdRequest = {3, "d t"};
```

There's no need to zero the structure if you're going to immediately fill in other values.

Comment: This should fill any remaining members with 0 too.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to do the assignment and cannot use an initialization, then you need to use a (C99 or later) compound literal:

```
cmdRequest = (cmdRequest_t){ 3, "d t" };
```

Comment: Pre-C99 it can be written `{ cmdRequest_t temp = { 3, "d t" }; cmdRequest = temp; }`

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Yes, that works, though it can be argued that it uses an initialization as well as the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Others have given the answer for initialisation already:

```
cmdRequest_t cmdRequest = {3, "d t"};
```

If by chance you wanted to reassign this struct, setting the first member to 42 and the second member (implicitly) to a null pointer, you could use this:

```
cmdRequest = (cmdRequest_t) { 42 };
```

If you wanted to reassign the struct, setting the second member, you'd need to use the name of the second member in the initialisation list. For example, if we consider that the second member is named *`fubar`*:

```
cmdRequest = (cmdRequest_t) { .fubar = "hello world" };
```

I advise explicitly initialising using the member names like this, because that way refactoring the struct at your whim becomes simple; you can change the order, the member names, etc, and the compiler will do most of the grunt work for you.